# composite aggregation vs nested terms aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation, elasticsearch-aggregation

Hi I am currently using nested terms aggregations (triple or more) to query elasticsearch. I would rather use the composite aggregation with 3+ source fields that i just discovered since it is way more manageable in my opinion, but I was wondering if performance-wise this is a bad choice. Any recommendation ?